# For what $x,y$ does $\sum_{k,l\ge 0} \frac{(k+l)!}{k!l!} \left| x^ky^l\right|$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

For what $x,y$ does $\sum_{k,l\ge 0} \frac{(k+l)!}{k!l!}  \left| x^ky^l\right|$ converge?

I think that $\sum_{k,l\ge 0}\left| x^ky^l\right|$ will converge for $|x|<1$ and $|y|<1$ since $\sum_{k,l\ge 0}\left| x^ky^l\right|= \left(\sum_{l\ge 0} \left|y^l \right| \right)\left(\sum_{k\ge 0} \left| x^k \right|\right)$

Since $(k+l)!\ge k!l!$ wont $\sum_{k,l\ge 0} \frac{(k+l)!}{k!l!}  \left| x^ky^l\right|$ converge for $|x|<1$ and $|y|<1$ also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need $|x|+|y|<1$. That should be necessary and sufficient.

This is because, re-arranging, this is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (|x|+|y|)^n$, where $n=k+l$.

Comment: How did you rearrange that?